# Add Data Labels with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a **Sub** based off a **checkbox** that I want to essentially switch between showing data labels on a graph and hiding them. I recorded the macro and altered it to no longer say **"Selection"** or **"ActiveChart"** because I don't want to have the user select the chart. I think that's where my problem is because it does absolutely nothing.

I can't seem to narrow down the issue since it's a rather long chunk. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub Checkbox()
Dim Cht As ChartObject
Set Cht = Sheet5.ChartObjects("Chart 12")
    If Sheet1.Range("W11") = "TRUE" Then
    Cht.Chart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelTop)
    Cht.Chart.ApplyDataLabels
    Cht.Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    Cht.ShowCategoryName = True
    Cht.Separator = "" & Chr(13) & ""
    With Cht.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(127, 127, 127)
        .Solid
    End With
    With Cht.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    With Cht.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(68, 114, 196)
        .Transparency = 0.75
        .Solid
    End With
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Else: Cht.Chart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelNone)
    End If
End Sub
```

I was told a while ago it's better to reference a cell rather than a checkbox, hence the reason I have the code looking at W11 for "TRUE" or "FALSE". I would rather use the checkbox if it seems practical.

Comment: I'd suggest stepping through your code (or using `debug.print`) to check that your `If` statement is flowing the way you'd expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that

```
If Sheet1.Range("W11") = "TRUE"
```

is not `true`.

If you `Debug.Print Sheet1.Range("W11") = "TRUE"` it will return `false` instead of the expected `true`. The cause is that `Sheet1.Range("W11")` returns a `boolean` not a `string` in this case.

You can verify the return type with

```
Debug.Print VarType(Sheet1.Range("W11"))
```

which returns `11` and that means `boolean` (see [VarType Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/vartype-function?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)).

---

So you should change it to

```
If Sheet1.Range("W11") = True
```

which is `true` if the cell W11 contains `TRUE`.

Comment: That makes sense, I can just replace that line with `If CheckBox1.Value = True Then` if I want to use a checkbox reference rather than a linked cell?

Comment: @KevinP. If it is a ActiveX checkbox then yes, if it is a form element checkbox then no. And you might need to specify the sheet If `Sheet1.CheckBox1.Value = True Then` if the code is in a module. If you used a form element checkbox instead of an ActiveX then you would need to use something like `If Sheet1.Shapes("CheckBox 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = xlOn Then`. I recommend to stay away from ActiveX if possible. Note that there might be a space in `CheckBox 1`.

Comment: Aside from the checkbox issue with either my original code and Xabiers I am still getting a functional error.

Comment: @KevinP. If you don't tell us which error you get and in which line of your original code we cannot help.

Comment: Sorry, I had posted the comment in the other answer. When unchecking, it removes the labels fine. When checking I get a "**Object doesn't support this property or method**". and it points to `Sheet5.Shapes("Chart 12").ShowCategoryName = True`

Comment: I have found the issue. Thank you for clarifying the debug.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, I believe you were referencing the chart incorrectly, by using the Shapes object, you can get to your desired chart:

```
Sub Checkbox()
    If Sheet1.Range("W11") = True Then
        Sheet1.Shapes("Chart 1").Chart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelShow)
        Sheet1.Shapes("Chart 1").Chart.ApplyDataLabels
        Sheet1.Shapes("Chart 1").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
        Sheet1.Shapes("Chart 1").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.ShowCategoryName = True
        Sheet1.Shapes("Chart 1").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Separator = "" & Chr(13) & ""
        With Sheet1.Shapes("Chart 1").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(127, 127, 127)
            .Solid
        End With
        With Sheet1.Shapes("Chart 1").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End With
        With Sheet1.Shapes("Chart 1").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(68, 114, 196)
            .Transparency = 0.75
            .Solid
        End With
        Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
    Else
        Sheet1.Shapes("Chart 1").Chart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelNone)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: When unchecking, it removes the labels fine. When checking I get a "**Object doesn't support this property or method**". and it points to `Sheet5.Shapes("Chart 12").ShowCategoryName = True`

Comment: @Kevin I forgot to add a couple of things, it should work as expected now, please see my updated answer. Also if this helps please could you mark my response as an answer? Thanks.

Comment: @Xabier `Sheet1.Range("W11") = "True"` will be `false` if the cell W11 contains `True` because it will return a boolean not a string. So this will not work as expected: See my answer.

Comment: @Peh, point taken and updated, thanks for your observation... :)

Comment: @Xabier I am still getting the same error in the same spot :(

Comment: @Xabier the issue was with the chart referencing even with the revised code. Once I changed some spots to Selection it worked. Please take a look at my answer if you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help I was able to figure out the issue. Below is the final code:

```
Sub Checkbox()
    If Sheet1.Range("W11") = True Then
    Sheet5.Shapes("Chart 12").Chart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelTop)
    Sheet5.Shapes("Chart 12").Chart.ApplyDataLabels
    Sheet5.Shapes("Chart 12").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
    Selection.ShowCategoryName = True
    Selection.Separator = "" & Chr(13) & ""
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(127, 127, 127)
        .Solid
    End With
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent1
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(68, 114, 196)
        .Transparency = 0.75
        .Solid
    End With
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
        Else
        Sheet5.Shapes("Chart 12").Chart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
        Sheet5.Shapes("Chart 12").Chart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelNone)
    End If
End Sub
```